# $ I = \int_0^1 ((y')^2-y^2)dx $ and $I_1= \int_0^1 (y' + y \tan x)^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let
>   $$ I = \int_0^1 ((y')^2-y^2)dx $$ and $$ I_1= \int_0^1 (y' + y \tan x)^2dx$$
>   where y is a given function of $x$ satisfying $y=0$ at $x=1$.
>   Show that $I - I_1 = 0$ and deduce that $I \geq 0$.
>   Show further that $I = 0$ only if $y=0$ for all $x$ $(0\leq x\leq 1)$

I can show the first part:
$$I_1 = I + [y^2\tan x]_0^1$$ leading to $$I-I_1 = 0$$

How do I do the rest?

> deduce that $I \geq 0$.
>   Show further that $I = 0$ only if $y=0$ for all $x$ $(0\leq x\leq 1)$

I don't know where to start from here

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $I_1 \geq 0$, as it is the integral if a non negative function.

Comment: Hint: $I_1>0 \rightarrow I>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $I_1=\int_0^1(y'+y\tan x)^2dx\ge 0$ since the integrand is non-negative.  Inasmuch as $I=I_1$, then $I\ge 0$.

The only way that $I=0$ is if $y'+y\tan x=0$ for all $x\epsilon [0,1]$.

This implies that for $y \ne 0$, $\log y=\log (\cos x) +C=0$ for all $x\epsilon [0,1]$.  But this latter solution is not possible.  This in turn implies  $y\equiv 0$.

Comment: @Dr. MV. Third line, May I ask why you made assumption that $\log y = \log(C\cos x) $ equals to $0$?

Comment: @zcahfg2 The ODE $y'+\tan x y=0$ has as solutions either the trivial solution $y=0$ or the solution $\log y=\log \cos x+C$ for some $C$, which implies $y=A\cos x$ for some constant $A$.  Of course, only the trivial solution is viable since $y(1)=0\implies A=0\implies y=0$

Answer (score 1):

You did the most complicate :-)
$$(y'+y\tan x)^2\geq 0\implies \int_0^1(y'+y\tan x)^2dx\geq 0$$

and

$$(y'+y\tan x)^2= 0\implies \int_0^1(y'+y\tan x)^2dx= 0.$$